# jQuery Event Not Working First time

Tags: jquery, events

I am trying to make datepicker using jQuery and jQueryUI

My date picker fires up only after designated event occures second time.

Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#id1" ).click(function() {
    $("#id1").datepicker();
    });
    });

</script>   


</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="id1" />
    </form>




</body>     

</html>
```

Here when I click on input box second time then datepicker appears but not on first click.

Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: Because you are only setting up datepicker after the first click. Have a look at the examples in the documentation to learn how it works: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `datepicker()` function isn't meant to be run on a click event.  That's the function that sets up that input box to trigger a datepicker -- it has it's own event handling.  Just run `datepicker()` at document ready, and don't worry about a click handler.